# Can't figure out why :nth-of-type won't work

Tags: css

I'm trying to select every 4th image in my div gallery. I can't seem to figure out why I can't select it.

```
#gallery img:nth-of-type(4n){
   border: 5px solid #000;
}
```

I've tried a few other ideas but to no success. Can anyone help me and explain to me why this isn't selecting every 4th image in my div gallery? Thanks in advance.

```
    <div id="gallery">

  <a href="/system/images/series_uploads/5/original/ankara_5602p_alabaster.jpg?1330114093" rel="lightbox['gallery']">
    <img alt="" src="/system/images/series_uploads/5/gallery/ankara_5602p_alabaster.jpg?1330114093" title="Ankara" />
    <div class="gallery-text">
      <h3>Ankara</h3>
      <p>Porcelain</p>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="/system/images/series_uploads/6/original/ankara_5624p_noce.jpg?1330114095" rel="lightbox['gallery']">
    <img alt="" src="/system/images/series_uploads/6/gallery/ankara_5624p_noce.jpg?1330114095" title="Ankara" />
    <div class="gallery-text">
      <h3>Ankara</h3>
      <p>Porcelain</p>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="/system/images/series_uploads/7/original/ashton_23931_smokey_beige_.jpg?1330114250" rel="lightbox['gallery']">
    <img alt="" src="/system/images/series_uploads/7/gallery/ashton_23931_smokey_beige_.jpg?1330114250" title="Ashton" />
    <div class="gallery-text">
      <h3>Ashton</h3>
      <p>Porcelain</p>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="/system/images/series_uploads/8/original/ashton_23942_camel_haze_entry.jpg?1330114251" rel="lightbox['gallery']">
    <img alt="" src="/system/images/series_uploads/8/gallery/ashton_23942_camel_haze_entry.jpg?1330114251" title="Ashton" />
    <div class="gallery-text">
      <h3>Ashton</h3>
      <p>Porcelain</p>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="/system/images/series_uploads/9/original/ashton_23942_camel_haze_lr.jpg?1330114252" rel="lightbox['gallery']">
    <img alt="" src="/system/images/series_uploads/9/gallery/ashton_23942_camel_haze_lr.jpg?1330114252" title="Ashton" />
    <div class="gallery-text">
      <h3>Ashton</h3>
      <p>Porcelain</p>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="/system/images/series_uploads/10/original/berkshire_25525_oak.jpg?1330115116" rel="lightbox['gallery']">
    <img alt="" src="/system/images/series_uploads/10/gallery/berkshire_25525_oak.jpg?1330115116" title="Berkshire" />
    <div class="gallery-text">
      <h3>Berkshire</h3>
      <p>HDP &ndash; High Definition Porcelain</p>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="/system/images/series_uploads/11/original/berkshire_25585_walnut_famousdaves01.jpg?1330115118" rel="lightbox['gallery']">
    <img alt="" src="/system/images/series_uploads/11/gallery/berkshire_25585_walnut_famousdaves01.jpg?1330115118" title="Berkshire" />
    <div class="gallery-text">
      <h3>Berkshire</h3>
      <p>HDP &ndash; High Definition Porcelain</p>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: please post the html markup aswell, since there is nothing wrong with the code here, there is probably where the issue is at

Comment: there updated with an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

they aren't siblings that's why you should use

```
#gallery a:nth-of-type(4n) img{
   border: 5px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: you're welcome, if it works please mark it as answered so future user can take part of it. Regards =)